# Running Total in Ms-access query using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to calculate running total in one of my access queries using SQL ( no DSUM please). 
I have 3 fields in my existing query Namely SubCategoryID, brand and Revenue and would like to calculate the running total of the revenue under each SubCategory.

I've written a query for it, but there is some error and I cant find a way to correct it.

```
    SELECT   x.SubCategoryID
            ,x.brand
            ,x.[Avg Revenue]
              ( Select Sum(x2.[Avg Revenue]) 
                From FROM [BrandRevenue] x2
                Where x2.[SubCategoryID] = x.[SubCategoryID] AND x2.[Avg Revenue] <= x.[Avg Revenue]) As [Running Sum]
    FROM (Select SubCategoryID, brand, [Avg Revenue]
          FROM [BrandRevenue]
          Order BY SubCategoryID, [Avg Revenue] DESC) As x
    Group BY x.SubCategoryID, x.brand, x.[Avg Revenue];
```

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: Care to share what the error is?

Comment: Syntax error in query expression 'Select Sum(x2.[Avg Revenue]) 
                From FROM [BrandRevenue(Weekly)] x2
                Where x2.[SubCategoryID] = x.[SubCategoryID] AND x2.[Avg Revenue] <= x.[Avg Revenue])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have repeated "From" in your correlated subquery:

```
  ( Select Sum(x2.[Avg Revenue]) 
    From FROM [BrandRevenue] x2
    ...
```

I don't think you need the subquery in the from clause, or the GROUP BY either. I think this will be better, and certainly simpler:

```
SELECT  x.SubCategoryID,
        x.brand,
        x.[Avg Revenue],
        (   SELECT  SUM(x2.[Avg Revenue]) 
            FROM    [BrandRevenue] x2
            WHERE   x2.[SubCategoryID] = x.[SubCategoryID] 
            AND     x2.[Avg Revenue] <= x.[Avg Revenue]
        ) AS [Running Sum]
FROM    BrandRevenue AS x
ORDER BY x.SubCategoryID, x.[Avg Revenue] DESC;
```

---

**ADDENUM**

I think to get around the problem of Brands having the same revenue you will need to add some additional logic to your correlated subquery:

```
SELECT  x.SubCategoryID,
        x.brand,
        x.[Avg Revenue],
        (   SELECT  SUM(x2.[Avg Revenue]) 
            FROM    [BrandRevenue] x2
            WHERE   x2.[SubCategoryID] = x.[SubCategoryID] 
            AND  (  x2.[Avg Revenue] <= x.[Avg Revenue]
                OR  (x2.[Avg Revenue] = x.[Avg Revenue] 
                AND x2.Brand <= x.Brand
                )
        ) AS [Running Sum]
FROM    BrandRevenue AS x
ORDER BY x.SubCategoryID, x.[Avg Revenue] DESC, x.Brand;
```

Comment: one problem though, the result is not as expected when the revenue of 2 brands is same. Any idea how to resolve this? thanks

Comment: I have added to the answer which should hopefully resolve the issue.